# Qt сравнить время

Tags: c++, qt, время

Мне нужно узнать, равно ли системное время нужному. 
Например, мне нужно, чтобы было 18:00, и узнать, равно ли системное время 18 часам.
Если, например, 15 часов, то ничего не делается. А если 18, то выполняется какое-то действие.

Comment: Поподробней опишите, как вы передаете время, которое нужно сравнивать с системным.

Comment: Просто беру число 18) Например, if (getCurrentHour() == 18) { doSomething(); }

Comment: если вы хотите в 18:00 каждый день выполнять какое-либо действие, то проще использовать средства системы такие как cron, Windows task scheduler. Иначе придётся самому функциональность реализовывать: заботиться, чтобы ваша программа при запуске системы запускалась, перезапускать её, если она завершилась по любой причине, следить что программа не зависла, следить что программа, которая следит за вашей программой также работает итд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то типа такого:

```
if (QTime::currentTime().hour() == 18){...}
```

Comment: Положим, >= не прокатит исходя из ТЗ

Comment: @HermannZheboldov да и в самом деле, что-то я подумал что больше 18.

Comment: Сравнивать на строгое равенство также нужно очень аккуратно.

Comment: Мне подходит, спасибо большое)))

Comment: @Vlad рекомендую почитать документацию на QTime ;-)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, тоже черезчур :) if(QTime::currentTime() == QTime(18, 0)) {...}

Comment: @HermannZheboldov Ну у вас тут новый объект создается, который не особо и нужен... Сравнение двух объектов наверняка будет сложнее сравнения целых... :-)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, но в Вашем случае условие будет срабатывать аж целый час, а не один раз. Хотя, может ТС это и нужно...